# Update version of Telerik Control in WPF application

Tags: telerik

I am new to WPF & Telerik Controls. I have an existing application in which Telerik controls with old version (2010.2.714.35) was used.

I installed a new version of Telerik controls (2012.2 912) from website and on my machine. I want to know about the steps to update my application's references according to new version.

Comment: I only use the Telerik productivity tools, but use the DevExpress component set. With DevExtress we get a tool that upgrades the solutions/projects. Are you sure there is not a similar tool for Telerik under the bin directory?

Comment: No sir there is no any tool to update the project.